# Permission denied GateKeeper warnings in the terminal when running macOS CLI tool even after signing and notarizing

Tags: xcode, osx-gatekeeper

I've been trying to get my CLI tool running without any GateKeeper UI's showing up, which makes the experience more annoying for users.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized what I was missing. I need a Info.plist embedded inside the binary, which is installed by the `.pkg` installer. This is because macOS GateKeeper looks for that when it launches the binary. I had to do 3 things:

- create an `Info.plist` somewhere in your project (I recommend the root of the project) which has at least 3 items, CFBundleIdentifier, CFBundleName, and CFBundleShortVersionString. I took this requirement from [Howard Oakley's blog post](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/13/building-and-delivering-command-tools-for-catalina/)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.example.example-cli-tool</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Example CLI Tool</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- Reference this `Info.plist` in the build settings: Set Info.plist File to the path, for example `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Info.plist`
- In Build Settings, I had to set `Create Info.plist Section in Binary` to Yes.

Then after I archived the project, build the package installer, downloaded it onto my machine, installed the package, I had no permission denied/ GateKeeper warnings.

---

I posted step by step actions to get an Xcode CLI project built and shipped, including notarization [here](https://orth.uk/cli-tools-building-signing-notarizing).